# Error while trying to read XML from URL in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to read a XML file from a URL and below is my code in .net core

```
 var url = "https://some.com/feeds/newfile.xml";
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 var result = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
 var stream = result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

 var itemXml = XElement.Load(stream);
```

When the debugger hits at .load, it throws an error

> error on line 22 at column 46: xmlParseEntityRef: no name

Below is the snapshot of the XML where the error occurs in line 22

```
<li>Win management’s support for your LOTO & machine guarding initiatives  </li>
```

Comment: *Don't* use `.Result`. It's no accident that HttpClient has no blocking methods. Mark your method `async` and use `await` to await for a response without blocking the thread

Comment: As for the error itself, it has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core. That's invalid XML *or* HTML.

Answer (score 2):

It's the & symbol - it's not valid XML.

You need to use &amp; as per the XML specification.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/